Classifying principal fiber bundles
In chapter 13 of The Topology of Fiber Bundles, by Steenrod, he states the following theorem:
"Let $X$ be a semi-locally 1- connected, arcwise connected and arcwise locally connected space. Let $G$ be a totally disconnected group. Then the equivalence classes of principal bundles over $X$ with group $G$ are in 1-1 correspondence with the equivalence classes of homomorphisms of $\pi_1(X)$ into $G$.
Can anyone give me another book in which this or a similar theorem is proven? My tescher said it was on Allen's Hatcher Algebraic Topology, but I can't seem to find it there. Would anyone give me an idea of why and how this theorem arises and is proven? I'm finding chapter 13 specially hard to read.

This almost certainly isn't in Hatcher because Hatcher does not discuss principal bundles at all. I don't know of a reference, but I think it's possible to cobble together something resembling a proof using modern techniques, here's an attempt at a sketch: Let's assume $G$ discrete and abelian. Then $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1 X, G) \cong H^1(X; G)$ (this should be in Hatcher), and $H^1(X; G) \cong [X, K(G, 1) = BG]$ (also Hatcher). Now $[X, BG]$ is in bijection with principal $G$-bundles on $X$ (Husemoller, perhaps?), q.e.d.

"Dale Husemoller, Fibre bundles" can be helpfull.

If $G$ isn't abelian, then the same argument should work replacing ordinary with Cech cohomology (afaik, but I don't know much about Cech cohomology), and if $G$ is not discrete then one needs to go through the hom-sets an verify that they are isomorphic to the discrete case (and verify that $BG$ is still a $K(G, 1)$, but that's easy).
